# Pass current element index to a function in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use code from [this example](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js) to create a set of independent lines as `path` elements:

```
svgContainer.append("path")
            .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
            .attr("stroke", "blue")
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("fill", "none");
```

As I have all lines data in lineData array, in each iteration I want to pass only a single item from it, like `lineFunction(lineData[i])`. My question is how can I get this current index as I can usually do with `someFunction(d, i){}` in D3?

Comment: You don't need to iterate for this, see e.g. [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955).

Answer (score 2):

You need to first bind to `lineData` in the typical d3 way. So:

```
svgContainer.selectAll('path').data(lineData).enter()
  .append("path")
    .attr("d", lineFunction)
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("fill", "none");
```

On the line

```
    .attr("d", lineFunction)
```

`lineFunction` the gets called with `d` and `i` as params, where `d` is the element in the array (which, if I understood, is an array of points). It's the same as doing

```
    .attr("d", function(d,i) { return lineFunction(d); }
```

which is the same as

```
    .attr("d", function(d,i) { return lineFunction( lineData[i]); }
```